# how i can use my ip address in this programm? if i put my address instead 127.0.0.1 the server not responce

Tags: c++

My problem in line:

```
server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
```

in client path. If i put my address instead 127.0.0.1 the server is not response.
I need to see the traffic in this program with wireshark packet sniffer...

```
 //Client   

#define TIME_PORT 27015
#define NUM_OF_REQUEST 5
#define SIZE 10
int getRequestFromUser();
float calculateAverage(int* arr);

void main() 
{
 //allocating memory to get the needed information from user 


    // Initialize Winsock (Windows Sockets).

 WSAData wsaData; 
 if (NO_ERROR != WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData))
 {
  cout<<"Time Client: Error at WSAStartup()\n";
 }

 // Client side:
 // Create a socket and connect to an internet address.

    SOCKET connSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
 if (INVALID_SOCKET == connSocket)
 {
        cout<<"Time Client: Error at socket(): "<<WSAGetLastError()<<endl;
        WSACleanup();
        return;
 }

 // For a client to communicate on a network, it must connect to a server.

 // Need to assemble the required data for connection in sockaddr structure.

    // Create a sockaddr_in object called server. 
 sockaddr_in server;
    server.sin_family = AF_INET; 
 server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
 server.sin_port = htons(TIME_PORT);

    // Send and receive data.

    int bytesSent = 0;
    int bytesRecv = 0;
 char sendBuff[255];
 char recvBuff[255];
 int requestFromUser = -1;

 while(requestFromUser != 0){

 requestFromUser=getRequestFromUser();
 // for mmeasure RTT/Delay
 float average=0;
 bool findDelay=false;
 bool findRTT=false;

 //matching between numbers and what they mean:
 switch (requestFromUser)
 {
 case 1:
  strcpy(sendBuff,"GetTime");
  break;
 case 2:
  strcpy(sendBuff,"GetTimeWithoutYear");
  break;
 case 3:
  strcpy(sendBuff,"GetTimeSinceEpoch");
  break;
 case 4:
  {
  strcpy(sendBuff,"GetClientToServerDelayEstimation");
  findDelay=true;
  break;
  }
 case 5:
  {
  strcpy(sendBuff,"MeasureRTT");
  findRTT=true;
  break;
  }
 case 6:
  {
   strcpy(sendBuff, "GetDayAndMonth");
   break;
  }
 default:
  ;//don't exist
 }

 // Asks the server what's the currnet time.
 // The send function sends data on a connected socket.
 // The buffer to be sent and its size are needed.
 // The fourth argument is an idicator specifying the way in which the call is made (0 for default).
 // The two last arguments hold the details of the server to communicate with. 
 // NOTE: the last argument should always be the actual size of the client's data-structure (i.e. sizeof(sockaddr)).

 if (findDelay)
 {
  int i;
  long int arrTimeR[SIZE];
  int arrTime[SIZE];
  time_t  arrTimeSend[SIZE];
  //Start sending the request
  strcpy(sendBuff,"GetTimeSinceEpoch");
  for (i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
  {

   //sending request
   bytesSent = sendto(connSocket, sendBuff, (int)strlen(sendBuff), 0, (const sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server));
   arrTimeSend[i]= time (NULL);
   if (SOCKET_ERROR == bytesSent)
   {
    cout<<"Time Client: Error at sendto(): "<<WSAGetLastError()<<endl;
    closesocket(connSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    return;
   }

   //recieving data
   bytesRecv = recv(connSocket, recvBuff, 255, 0);

   if (SOCKET_ERROR == bytesRecv)
   {
    cout<<"Time Client: Error at recv(): "<<WSAGetLastError()<<endl;
    closesocket(connSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    return;
   }
   recvBuff[bytesRecv]='\0';
   arrTime[i]=atoi(recvBuff)-(arrTimeSend[i]);

  }//for 
  average=calculateAverage(arrTime);
  cout<< "The average Delay between Client to Server is "<<average<<" in seconds\n";

 }//findDelay

 if (findRTT)
 {
  int i;
  time_t timerD;
  time_t arrTimeSend[SIZE];
  int arrTime[SIZE];
  strcpy(sendBuff,"GetTime"); 

  for (i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
  {

   //getting time of sending I'm including all operations for sending the request to the server

   arrTimeSend[i]=time (NULL);
   //sending request
   bytesSent = sendto(connSocket, sendBuff, (int)strlen(sendBuff), 0, (const sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server));

   if (SOCKET_ERROR == bytesSent)
   {
    cout<<"Time Client: Error at sendto(): "<<WSAGetLastError()<<endl;
    closesocket(connSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    return;
   }
  }//for sending
  for (i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
  {
   //recieving data
   bytesRecv = recv(connSocket, recvBuff, 255, 0);

   //getting time of recieving
   timerD = time (NULL);

   if (SOCKET_ERROR == bytesRecv)
   {
    cout<<"Time Client: Error at recv(): "<<WSAGetLastError()<<endl;
    closesocket(connSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    return;
   }

   recvBuff[bytesRecv]='\0';//not needed for calculation , but for future use
   arrTime[i]=difftime(timerD,arrTimeSend[i]);
  }//for receving
  average=calculateAverage(arrTime);
  cout<< "The average RTT time is "<<average<<" in seconds\n";
 }//findRTT
 if (!findRTT && !findDelay)
 {
  bytesSent = sendto(connSocket, sendBuff, (int)strlen(sendBuff), 0, (const sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server));
  if (SOCKET_ERROR == bytesSent)
  {
   cout<<"Time Client: Error at sendto(): "<<WSAGetLastError()<<endl;
   closesocket(connSocket);
   WSACleanup();
   return;
  }
  cout<<"Time Client: Sent: "<<bytesSent<<"/"<<strlen(sendBuff)<<" bytes of \""<<sendBuff<<"\" message.\n";

  // Gets the server's answer using simple recieve (no need to hold the server's address).
  bytesRecv = recv(connSocket, recvBuff, 255, 0);
  if (SOCKET_ERROR == bytesRecv)
  {
   cout<<"Time Client: Error at recv(): "<<WSAGetLastError()<<endl;
   closesocket(connSocket);
   WSACleanup();
   return;
  }

  recvBuff[bytesRecv]='\0'; //add the null-terminating to make it a string
  cout<<"Time Client: Recieved: "<<bytesRecv<<" bytes of \""<<recvBuff<<"\" message.\n";
 }//(!findRTT && !findDelay) 
}//End of while
  // Closing connections and Winsock.
  cout<<"Time Client: Closing Connection.\n";
  closesocket(connSocket);

  //free the allocating memory 

}//main

//==================
int getRequestFromUser()
{ 
 int num=0; 
 //int index=0;
 //char c;
 cout<<"Choose the information that you intrested in:"<<endl;
 cout<<"(1) - Get time"<<endl;
 cout<<"(2) - Get time without Year"<<endl;
 cout<<"(3) - Get time since epoch - meanning since 1.1.1970"<<endl;
 cout<<"(4) - Get dilay time "<<endl;
 cout<<"(5) - measuring RTT - round trip time"<<endl;
 cout<<"(6) - Get day and month"<<endl;
 cout<<"(0) - Exit"<<endl;

 cin>>num;

 return num;

}
float calculateAverage(int* arr)
{
 int sum=0,i;
 for (i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
  sum+=arr[i];

 return sum/SIZE;
}


//Server

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <iomanip>


#define TIME_PORT 27015

void main() 
{
    // Initialize Winsock (Windows Sockets).
 // Create a WSADATA object called wsaData.
    // The WSADATA structure contains information about the Windows 
 // Sockets implementation.

 WSAData wsaData; 

 // Call WSAStartup and return its value as an integer and check for errors.
 // The WSAStartup function initiates the use of WS2_32.DLL by a process.
 // First parameter is the version number 2.2.
 // The WSACleanup function destructs the use of WS2_32.DLL by a process.

 if (NO_ERROR != WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData))
 {
        cout<<"Time Server: Error at WSAStartup()\n";
 }

 // Server side:
 // Create and bind a socket to an internet address.
    // After initialization, a SOCKET object is ready to be instantiated.
 // Create a SOCKET object called m_socket. 
 // For this application: use the Internet address family (AF_INET), 
 //       datagram sockets (SOCK_DGRAM), 
 //       and the UDP/IP protocol (IPPROTO_UDP).

    SOCKET m_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);

 // Check for errors to ensure that the socket is a valid socket.
 // Error detection is a key part of successful networking code. 
 // If the socket call fails, it returns INVALID_SOCKET. 
 // The "if" statement is used to catch any errors that
 // may have occurred while creating the socket. WSAGetLastError returns an 
 // error number associated with the last error that occurred.

 if (INVALID_SOCKET == m_socket)
 {
        cout<<"Time Server: Error at socket(): "<<WSAGetLastError()<<endl;
        WSACleanup();
        return;
 }

 // For a server to communicate on a network, it must first bind the socket to 
 // a network address.
 // Need to assemble the required data for connection in sockaddr structure.

    // Create a sockaddr_in object called serverService. 

 sockaddr_in serverService;

 // Address family (must be AF_INET - Internet address family).

    serverService.sin_family = AF_INET; 

 // IP address. The sin_addr is a union (s_addr is a unsigdned long (4 bytes) data type).
 // INADDR_ANY means to listen on all interfaces.
 // inet_addr (Internet address) is used to convert a string (char *) into unsigned int.
 // inet_ntoa (Internet address) is the reverse function (converts unsigned int to char *)
 // The IP address 127.0.0.1 is the host itself, it's actually a loop-back.

 serverService.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; //inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

 // IP Port. The htons (host to network - short) function converts an
 // unsigned short from host to TCP/IP network byte order (which is big-endian).

 serverService.sin_port = htons(TIME_PORT);

 // Bind the socket for client's requests.
    // The bind function establishes a connection to a specified socket.
 // The function uses the socket handler, the sockaddr structure (which
 // defines properties of the desired connection) and the length of the
 // sockaddr structure (in bytes).

    if (SOCKET_ERROR == bind(m_socket, (SOCKADDR *) &serverService, sizeof(serverService))) 
 {
  cout<<"Time Server: Error at bind(): "<<WSAGetLastError()<<endl;
        closesocket(m_socket);
  WSACleanup();
        return;
    }

    // Waits for incoming requests from clients.
    // Send and receive data.

 sockaddr client_addr;
 int client_addr_len = sizeof(client_addr);
 int bytesSent = 0;
    int bytesRecv = 0;
 char sendBuff[255];
 char recvBuff[255];

 // Get client's requests and answer them.
 // The recvfrom function receives a datagram and stores the source address.
 // The buffer for data to be received and its available size are 
 // returned by recvfrom. The fourth argument is an idicator 
 // specifying the way in which the call is made (0 for default).
 // The two last arguments are optional and will hold the details of the client for further communication. 
 // NOTE: the last argument should always be the actual size of the client's data-structure (i.e. sizeof(sockaddr)).

 cout<<"Time Server: Wait for clients' requests.\n"; 

 while(true)
 {
  bytesRecv = recvfrom(m_socket, recvBuff, 255, 0, &client_addr, &client_addr_len);
  if (SOCKET_ERROR == bytesRecv)
  {
   cout<<"Time Server: Error at recvfrom(): "<<WSAGetLastError()<<endl;
   closesocket(m_socket);
   WSACleanup();
   return;
  }

  recvBuff[bytesRecv]='\0'; //add the null-terminating to make it a string

  cout<<"Time Server: Recieved: "<<bytesRecv<<" bytes of \""<<recvBuff<<"\" message.\n";

  time_t timer;
  time(&timer);
  char date [10];
  char dayAndMonth [6];

  //1-GetTime
  if (strcmp(recvBuff,"GetTime")==0){
   strcpy(sendBuff, ctime(&timer));
   sendBuff[strlen(sendBuff)-1] = 0;
  }

  //2-GetTimeWithoutYear
  else if (strcmp(recvBuff,"GetTimeWithoutYear")==0){
   struct tm * timeinfo = localtime(&timer);
   strftime (sendBuff,255,"%X",timeinfo);
   sendBuff[strlen(sendBuff)] = 0;
  }

  //3-GetTimeSinceEpoch
  else if (strcmp(recvBuff,"GetTimeSinceEpoch")==0){ 
   timer = time (NULL);
   itoa(timer,sendBuff,10);//converting from int to srting 
   strcat (sendBuff," seconds.");
   sendBuff[strlen(sendBuff)] = 0;
  }
  //6 - GetDayAndMonth
  else if(strcmp(recvBuff, "GetDayAndMonth")==0)
  {
   _tzset;
   _strdate(date);
   strncpy(dayAndMonth, date, 5);
   dayAndMonth[5] = '\0';
   strcpy(sendBuff, dayAndMonth);
   sendBuff[strlen(sendBuff)] = 0;
  }

  // Sends the answer to the client, using the client address gathered
  // by recvfrom. 
  bytesSent = sendto(m_socket, sendBuff, (int)strlen(sendBuff), 0, (const sockaddr *)&client_addr, client_addr_len);
  if (SOCKET_ERROR == bytesSent)
  {
   cout<<"Time Server: Error at sendto(): "<<WSAGetLastError()<<endl;
   closesocket(m_socket);
   WSACleanup();
   return;
  }

  cout<<"Time Server: Sent: "<<bytesSent<<"\\"<<strlen(sendBuff)<<" bytes of \""<<sendBuff<<"\" message.\n"; 
 }

 // Closing connections and Winsock.
 cout<<"Time Server: Closing Connection.\n";
 closesocket(m_socket);
 WSACleanup();
}
```

Comment: Hi Oleg, that's wayyyy too much data. You should add some text with a description of your problem instead

Comment: it may be because your server listens `localhost` (`127.0.0.1`) and not that particular interface you are trying to connect. Please post the server code (if you have) or make sure you know what network interface it listens. Please don't add your comments/updates as an answer. You should edit the quesion, or put a comment here. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry for comments, it my first time i use this site. How i can listen (in server side) to specific ip address. I want to run this client\server on my computer and use only my ip address.

Comment: inet_addr was even deprecated in 2010 if I recall correctly.

Answer (score 1):

My problem in line: 
server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
in client path. If i put my address instead 127.0.0.1 the server is not response.
I need to see the traffic in this program with wireshark packet sniffer...

Answer (score 0):

You may want to perform some **ping YOUR_SERVER** command first or figure out with exception handling, may be your server is not available.

Comment: I think you meant `telnet` when wrote `ping`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have to use the loopback address (127.0.0.1) to communicate with your server, and the problem is that, if you do this, you can't see the traffic in Wireshark.

It that is right, and assuming (as your code suggests) that you are on Windows, I'm afraid that you are out of luck. See this: http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Loopback

Can you change the server to have it listening on another address?